# How to make shortcode output display where I choose

Tags: shortcode, text

There are tons of post about this, but in my case, i see no echo(so i can change for return) in the shortcode.php file of the plug in, i did not developed this plug in, i need to fix the problem that output shows always first instead where i put it.
Sorry for the duplactes, i read every single post i could find about this, and no answer could match this shortcode structure.
I am good at this matter, but zero preparation on php, just know and learned of experience and reading, so have patience with me :D
The code i think where i need to edit to fix it is this:

```
#init function for shortcode
public function __construct()
{
    $shortcodes = self::shortcode_manager();
    foreach($shortcodes as $shortcode => $handler)
    {
        add_shortcode($shortcode,$handler);
    }
    add_filter('the_content', array('ipray_shortcode','content_filter'));
}
```

Comment: We need to see the content of `ipray_shortcode::content_filter()`.